# Compile error on a method that calculate a Future[List[(String, Int)]]

Tags: mongodb, scala, asynchronous, playframework, future

I'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application in Scala.

I am using a MongoDB database with the `reactivemongo` driver.

In my project, I have two collections: a `recommendation.tags` collection that stores all the tags used in my application, and the `recommendation.requests` collection that stores the request user and the associated tags.

A document of the `recommendation.tags` collection looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("545211fefcacc71587d5fe7b"),
    "tag" : "Beverage:Tea - Camomele  & Beverages"
}
```

A document of the `recommendation.requests` looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54521395fcacc71587d600db"),
    "id" : "c9f7eda2-70c2-473e-94dd-3ecb6cabb0b8",
    "user" : {
        "id" : "5452138b2318ab1f91ccd254",
        "email" : "rgutierrez@livefish.info"
    },
    "tags" : [
        {
            "tag" : "Canned/Jarred Goods:Rice - Aborio"
        },
        {
            "tag" : "Fish:Swordfish Loin Portions"
        },
        {
            "tag" : "Alcool:Wine - Touraine Azay - Le - Rideau"
        }
    ],
    "date" : 1414665108468
}
```

The `"date"` represents the date in milliseconds format.

Now, I'm writing a method that, for every tag (the `"tag"` field in the `recommendation.tags` collection), it counts the number of times that the tag's value equals the `"tags"` field of the `recommendation.requests` collection.

I have tried to implement the method like this:

```
   def calculate(range: Range): Future[Option[List[(String, Int)]]] = {

   val futureTags: Future[List[(String, Int)]] = Tags.all.toList map {tags => tags map {tag => //calculate the occurrences for every tag
     val tagName = tag.category + ":" + tag.attr
     val tagCondition = Json.obj("tags.tag" -> tagName)
     val gte = Json.obj("date" -> Json.obj("$gte" -> range.startDate))
     val lte = Json.obj("date" -> Json.obj("$lte" -> range.finishDate))
     val query = Json.obj("$and" -> Json.arr(tagCondition, gte, lte))
     Requests.find(query).toList flatMap {results => (tagName, results.size)
      //return the (tagName, occurrences) 
     }
   }
   }

    futureTags flatMap {tags =>
      if(tags.size > 0) {
        val correctList = for(el <- tags; if(el._2 > 0)) yield el
        Future{Some(correctList)}
      } else Future{None}
    }
  }
```

`Range` is a class defined like this:

```
case class Range (
      startDate: Long,
      finishDate: Long)
```

But the compiler gives me the following errors:

```
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/controllers/StatisticsController.scala:168: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : List[scala.concurrent.Future[(String, Int)]]
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[List[(String, Int)]]
[error]    val futureTags: Future[List[(String, Int)]] = Tags.all.toList flatMap {tags => tags map {tag =>
[error]                                                                                        ^
[error] one error found
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/controllers/StatisticsController.scala:168: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : List[scala.concurrent.Future[(String, Int)]]
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[List[(String, Int)]]
[error]    val futureTags: Future[List[(String, Int)]] = Tags.all.toList flatMap {tags => tags map {tag =>
[error]
```

I can't understand what is wrong with the use of Future.

Comment: Future.traverse(tags) { tag => ...

Comment: @viktortnk I've put the Future.traverse() as first instruction but It don't compile, where I have to put the Future.traverse instruction?

Answer (score 0):

I think the flatmap

```
Requests.find(query).toList flatMap { results => 
    (tagName, results.size)
}
```

should be replaced by a map

```
Requests.find(query).toList map { results => 
    (tagName, results.size)
}
```

When you flatmap then it expects a list of lists, which will then be flattened to a list. You are using flatMap and only return a single tuple

Comment: It's not expecting a list of lists, but nested `Future`s, in this case.

Comment: @Rovak I've changed my code as suggested by you, but the code don't compile. I've updated my post.